# Orchard CMS: Invoking two actions leads to duplicate notifications

Tags: c#-4.0, razor, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Our Orchard application displays two of all notifications that are added to the notification service. So far we have traced the problem and know what is causing it, but are looking for a solution other than the obvious, for reasons I shall now elaborate.

So we are using a number of themes to render our Orchard based application. Within our layout, we have a Razor call to draw a header bar that displays a set of information about the user that is logged in.

```
@Html.Action("OutOfGameHeader", "Options", new { area = "Area.area.Location.Common" })
```

This action calls the OnResultExecuting() method in Orchard.UI.Notify.NotifyFilter which (among other things) populates the Messages Zone with the current set of notifications. When we make the call the render the Messages Zone, this same method runs again and the notifications are added to the Zone's shape again resulting in duplicate notification being displayed when the Zone is actually drawn.

Can anyone think of a solution that meets the following criteria:

- Drawing the header without calling @Html.Action() to avoid OnResultExecuting() being triggered the first time.
- Without creating a new Widget in a new Zone as this would involve us changing the manifest for dozens of existing themes to include it.

We also found this just below the point in the code where the notifications are added to the Zone, so if anyone knows anything more about it, that would be helpful too.

```
//todo: (heskew) probably need to keep duplicate messages from being pushed into the zone like the previous behavior
//baseViewModel.Messages = baseViewModel.Messages == null ? messageEntries .Messages.Union(messageEntries).ToList();
//baseViewModel.Zones.AddRenderPartial("content:before", "Messages", baseViewModel.Messages);
```

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid Html.Action. This runs through the whole lifecycle as if this was a new request. That you think you need it is often a sign that you need to refactor and extract that logic that you want to re-use out of your controller. In Orchard, it's also better to use dynamic shapes.

Comment: +1 Html.Action and Html.RenderAction are evil:) As Bertrand wrote, this clearly indicates your code needs refactoring as you have too much logic in your controllers.